# Agora Web SDK v4 SEND_VIDEO_BITRATE_TOO_LOW and SEND_AUDIO_BITRATE_TOO_LOW

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am implementing Agora v4 in my application. When I am trying to publish my local tracks, it happens with success, but then I receive the following errors:

01:21:17:806 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [client-9e8ac] receive exception msg, code: 2001, msg: AUDIO_INPUT_LEVEL_TOO_LOW, uid: 4082215569
index.ts:269 01:21:17:807 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [client-9e8ac] receive exception msg, code: 2003, msg: SEND_AUDIO_BITRATE_TOO_LOW, uid: 4082215569
index.ts:269 01:21:17:807 Agora-SDK [DEBUG]: [client-9e8ac] receive exception msg, code: 1003, msg: SEND_VIDEO_BITRATE_TOO_LOW, uid: 4082215569

```
const agoraAccessToken = await actions.auth.getAgoraAccessToken({ requestParams: {channel: props.config.channel}});
    console.log(agoraAccessToken);


    let uid = await AgoraClient.join(props.config.appId, props.config.channel, agoraAccessToken);
    console.log(uid);

    let audioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
    let videoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack();

    await AgoraClient.publish([audioTrack, videoTrack]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setVideoEncoderConfiguration` for setting a minimum and maximum limit in terms of frameRate and bitrate which automatically gets adjusted according to network speed.

Example: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/video_profile_web_ng?platform=Web.